# Can we shift the diatonic scale "one fifth" to the left?

Tags: theory, scales, intervals, diatonic

The seven-note Pythagorean scale is obtain by completing the cycle of fifths until we get to the eighth fifth.

The diatonic scale is obtained by starting with the fourth and then running the cycle of fifths until we get to the eighth fifth. Contrary to the seven-note Pythagorean scale, the note corresponding to 1 is in second position in the cycle of fifths (whereas in the seven-note Pythagorean scale, it is in first position).

My question is, are there other seven-note musical scales, for example a seven-note musical scale that has the note corresponding to 1 in third position in the cycle of fifths?

Are they popular? Or do they exist just in theory but remain unused?

Comment: The definitions you give for the Pythagorean scale and for the diatonic scale are equivalent.  The question is therefore rather unclear.  Can you perhaps give an example of each kind of scale illustrating your understanding of the difference between them?  I mean, if you start on C and generate the Pythagorean scale using the procedure you describe, you get a scale with no F but an F sharp, so it's a G major scale, and we end up with the same scale that we would have gotten by using the "diatonic" procedure.

Comment: I am totally new to music theory, I may have misunderstood something. As far as I have understood, C D E F# G A B is one example of the seven-note Pythagorean scale (starting with C). C D E F G A B is one example of the diatonic scale starting with C.

Comment: Also, I think I understand your point. Thanks for the help

Comment: @niobium, I think you see that the series of P5 up from `C` ends on `F#` might seem to be in conflict with a `C` major scale. While that is not necessarily the case, you might be interested in George Russell and his Chromatic Lydian Concept. As I understand it, Russell felt that series made the lydian scale rather than the major scale the basis for harmony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wording of the question is a little unclear.

You don't need to move by perfect fifths eight time to get seven tones, only six jumps by perfect fifth will give you seven tones. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "shift". Probably you mean *rotation of a scale*, but it might also be understood to mean *transpose*.

Anyway, ascending perfect fifths, starting at `C`, and stopping at seven tones, will be...

`C G D A E B F#`

You can call that scale `G` major, `C` lydian, etc. depending on which tone you choose to be the *tonic*.

Depending on the meaning of shift we can do a number of things to that series of tones.

You can shift - extend a perfect fifth to the left, and the seven tones would become...

`F C G D A E B`

Or, if the tones are arranged by letter steps...

`C D E F# G A B`

...a diatonic shift to the left by fifth (diminished in this case) would be...

`F# G A B C D E`

On the other hand if you mean transpose a (perfect) fifth down, it would be...

`F B A B C D E`

You can do many procedure, but if the end result is seven tones that can be rearranged into a series of perfect fifths, then you will have a collection of diatonic tones, and the various way of ordering such a series by letter steps will have scale or mode names.

For details you can look up concepts like *[modes of the diatonic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatonic_scale#Modes).*